# What js files do I need to include to use ExtJs Calendar?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, include, calendar

I want to play around with the ExtJs calendar and was wondering which js files i will need to include to do so?
The example from the Ext website includes many js files and I am wondering which ones are necessary and which ones are not. I'm assuming it depends on what functionality I wish the calendar to have, so lets just say I want to expose all of its functionality for now.
the following is a list of js and css files from the example on the Ext website:

```
 <!-- Calendar-specific includes --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/calendar.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/Ext.calendar.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/templates/DayHeaderTemplate.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/templates/DayBodyTemplate.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/templates/DayViewTemplate.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/templates/BoxLayoutTemplate.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/templates/MonthViewTemplate.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/dd/CalendarScrollManager.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/dd/StatusProxy.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/dd/CalendarDD.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/dd/DayViewDD.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/EventRecord.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/MonthDayDetailView.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/widgets/CalendarPicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/WeekEventRenderer.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/CalendarView.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/MonthView.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/DayHeaderView.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/DayBodyView.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/DayView.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/views/WeekView.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/widgets/DateRangeField.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/widgets/ReminderField.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/EventEditForm.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/EventEditWindow.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/CalendarPanel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calender is not included with the main extjs javascript files. You can use the calendar-all.js with the CSS instead of having the individual files added from the src directory. The calendar-all.js file is available in the calendar example folder itself.

So, you will require:

```
<!-- CSS files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/calendar.css" />
<!-- Scripts -->   
<script type="text/javascript" src="adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendar-all.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you know where i can find any good documentation/ examples of how to use the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can also check out [Ext Calendar Pro](http://ext.ensible.com/products/calendar) as well, which is the full product version of the example that shipped with 3.3. (Full disclosure: I am the author)

It has additional [examples](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/) and complete [docs](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/) and many bugs have been fixed since that example was created.

But yes, if you just want to play around with the one in 3.3 simply include `calendar-all.js` as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need this ones:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
```

Everything else is loaded by Ext JS by itself.